# Could XmlBuilder.processing accept more arguments?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, dart

Would it be possible to add more info when building and xml doc with [dart-xml](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml)?

Both of the following work fine for building xml, xslt.

```
builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"'); 
builder.processing('xml-stylesheet', 'type="application/xml"');
```

With xml I'd like to add UTF instructions to help internationalization.

```
builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0"', 'encoding="UTF-8"');
//gives error '2 positional arguments expected, but 3 found'
```

Trying to link to XSLT would be helpful.

```
builder.processing('xml-stylesheet', 'type="application/xml"', href="hieroglyph.xsl"); 
//gives 2 errors; '2 positional arguments expected, but 3 found' 
//'Undefined name 'href''
```

I think this is is set within [dart-xml/lib/xml/grammar.dart](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml/blob/master/lib/xml/grammar.dart) and the processing() method.

```
 processing() => string(OPEN_PROCESSING)
      .seq(ref(nameToken))
      .seq(ref(space)
          .seq(any().starLazy(string(CLOSE_PROCESSING)).flatten())
          .pick(1)
          .optional(''))
      .seq(string(CLOSE_PROCESSING))
      .map((each) => createProcessing(each[1], each[2]));
  qualified() => ref(nameToken).map(createQualified);
```

Normal Xml elements can have 0,1 or many args so how would I enable processing() to do this? Is it a matter of changing a list to include more than 2 args or would it be more complicated and entail adding other definitions like 'href' for xslt or others for xsd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, [dart-xml](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml) parses processing instructions as described in the [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createProcessingInstruction). This means the parser simply splits everything between `<?` and `?>` into a `target` and a `data` string.

Thus, the builder expects two strings as argument as well. You can simply write:

```dart
 builder.processing('xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"');
 builder.processing('xml-stylesheet', 'type="application/xml" href="hieroglyph.xsl"');
```

Probably it would be a good idea to add a method to the builder to simplify the creation of such XML declarations. Feel free file an issue.

Comment: Hi Rengli, no it doesn't work. for some reason there's a limit on the args that builder.processing can accept. It returns the errors that I've typed above. I'll keep trying. I've also opened a general issue on the dart-xml repo to see if anyone has any ideas or input when they have time.

Comment: I've added the example as a test to [GitHub](https://github.com/renggli/dart-xml/commit/dc2adbd3d28abac1b08acf33174c71ca2b7afe44). Please note that processing takes two arguments: the first argument is the target, and the second argument is the data (that just happens to look like two attributes in your example).

Comment: I think I see what you have done to make this work; just remove the comma and apostrophy and turn two args into one. This leaves you with a target and a data string. "'xml', 'version="1.0"', 'encoding="UTF-8"' becomes "'xml', 'version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"'"     This works fine for me. Tks.